# How to determine why Ubuntu start to load slowly?

Tags: 14.04, restart

Recently my installation start to load visibly slowly. 
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which after initial install have fabulous loading time but recently the time for full loading from complete shutdown is visibly longer.
It's not something that is annoying but could I check if something is slowing my system?

Comment: type `dmesg` in terminal.

Comment: Check the dmesg log (`dmesg | less`), it has time stamps, so look for large gaps.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever and @kashish I didn't know about `dmesg` command after executing it the largest gap is at last line with following warning `Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed` as I understand it this is due to many old host names  in my /etc/hosts file will try to clean it and check again if there will be some noticeable change

Comment: It turns out that this is the problem I commented out in `/etc/hosts` not enabled host names in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and largest gap and warning disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking what was causing the problem was done with `dmesg` command which list loading time and process.

The problem with slow start time was caused by miss configuration in `/etc/hosts` file there was multiple lines of localhost names used for development that are not enabled in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

So when checking with `dmesg | less` on the last line there were time gap of 800 sec. and warning `Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed`.

After commenting out not enabled host names the loading drop from 800 to 53 sec.